# How to update document with specific version

Tags: prisma

I have a use case where my function first gets a user record, does some work on it and then updates it. To guarantee correct operation, I need to ensure that user record was not updated while such work is being done. Typically, I would do this by adding version to my user model, thus I get current version and update based on this exact version (auto incrementing it with each update), however I am getting a strange uniqueness error that I am not able to figure out:

User model

```
model User {
  uid       String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  version   Int      @default(0)
  email     String   @unique
}
```

Update opperation

```
prisma.user.update({
  where: { uid, version },
  data: { ...newData, version: { increment: 1 } }
})
```

Version is highlighted with following error

> Type '{ uid: string; version: number; }' is not assignable to type
> 'UserWhereUniqueInput'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'version' does not exist in type
> 'UserWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need a unique clause to use a where clause on a simple update.
Prisma ask you to give it a unique contraint for this type of update, like for the where clause in a findUnique. Currently you unique constraint is on the `email` field

Here you have 2 solutions

**The good practice?**

Add a unique constraint between `uid` and `version`

```js
model User {
  uid       String   @id @default(uuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  version   Int      @default(0)
  email     String   @unique

  // new unique constraint
  @@unique([uid, version])
}
```

and then you can do your update with the new unique constraint

```js
prisma.user.update({
  where: { uid_version: { uid, version } },
  data: { ...newData, version: { increment: 1 } }
})
```

**Easy win**

If you want, you can also do an updateMany that will not need a unique constraint to filter

```js
prisma.user.updateMany({
  where: { uid, version },
  data: { ...newData, version: { increment: 1 } }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Assuming version field changes often, is it still recommended to create this unique index on it and uuid?